# PHP get create time of directory

Tags: php

Is there anyway to find the created time of a directory in php? I've tried `filectime` but that only works on files.

Comment: *(sidenote)* `filectime` is *change time* on Linux. It's only on Windows that it returns creation time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should work for directories, this is what I get:

```
$ php -r "echo filectime(__DIR__);"
1311596297
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out I had the incorrect path to the folders specified.

Comment: Please note Gordon's comment above: `filectime` will give you the time of the **last change** on Unix servers, which might or might not be the same as the creation time.

Answer (score 8):

In unix a folder is also a file. So it should work for that too

```
$folder = 'includes';

echo date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($folder));
```

Output is

```
October 06 2010 20:20:58.
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the PHP [stat function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php):

> Gathers the statistics of the file named by filename. If filename is a symbolic link, statistics are from the file itself, not the symlink.

**Sample:**

```
<?php
    $stat = stat('/your/path');
    echo $stat['ctime'];
?>
```

It returns the create time as Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

**No. Not reliably.**

That's because `ctime` is not about creation, but change, as pointed out in Gordon's comment. So while `filectime()` does work on directories (at least on a Unix machine), chances are it will not give you the date you are looking for. See the notes on the [PHP Doc page for `filectime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php):

> Note also that in some Unix texts the ctime of a file is referred to as being the creation time of the file. This is wrong. There is no creation time for Unix files in most Unix filesystems.

In other words, creating a new file in a directory will likely change the `ctime` of the directory. If you really need to keep track of the *creation* time, you need to implement the housekeeping yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
print_r( stat('/path') )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$filename = 'media/';
echo "$filename was created modified: ".date("F d Y H:i:s.", filectime($filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

if (it dose not work)
try **clearstatcache();** before your **filectime** function;

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename='dirname';
date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filectime($filename))
```

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I tested both the function filectime() and filemtime() on a Linux server and they 
work correctly on directories, too, in the sense that they return a timestamp.

Then, I tried to get the last modified date of a directory, renaming it via FTP and then checking it again, and here's the strange thing that happened:

1. the creation date timestamp was updated with the current time
2. the last modified date was not updated at all

I think this may have occurred because of the FTP file manipulation instead of a direct manipulation through the command line or the system graphical interface.

On Windows, both the creation date and the last modified date do not change when renaming a directory.

For your tests, I also suggest you to have a look at the clearstatcache() function (which I also used in my test) to clear the PHP cache of the filesystem information.